# Why can we claim that $c^{2}\mathbb{V}(U) + 2c\mathbb{E}(TU) \geq 0$ implies that $\mathbb{E}(TU) = 0$?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, variance, covariance

Suppose that $T$ is a UMVUE for $\theta$. Then let $T_{c} = T + cU$ where $U$ is an unbiased estimator of zero and $c\in\mathbb{R}$ is a fixed constant. Hence $T_{c}$ is also unbiased for $\theta$, whence we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{V}(T_{c}) \geq \mathbb{V}(T),
\end{align*}
for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and every $\theta\in\Theta$ (the parametric space). According to the properties of variance, it is the same as to claim that
\begin{align*}
c^{2}\mathbb{V}(U) + 2c\text{Cov}(T,U) \geq 0,
\end{align*}
for every $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\theta\in\Theta$. However, since $\mathbb{E}(U) = 0$, we can conclude that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{V}(U) = \mathbb{E}(U^{2}) - [\mathbb{E}(U)]^{2} = \mathbb{E}(U^{2})\\\\
\text{Cov}(T,U) = \mathbb{E}(TU) - \mathbb{E}(T)\mathbb{E}(U) = \mathbb{E}(TU)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
Consquently, one arrives at the follow relation:
\begin{align*}
c^{2}\mathbb{E}(U^{2}) + 2c\mathbb{E}(TU) \geq 0
\end{align*}
But then I get stuck. How do we conclude from here that $\mathbb{E}(TU) = 0$?

Comment: You have $a x^2 + b x \geq 0$ for all $x$ and you are asking why $b = 0$? Note you can assume $a = 1$ and then consider $x$ negative and small.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line is a quadratic in $c$, which is $\ge 0$ for all $c$ and $=0$ for some $c$ ($c=0$). So its discriminant must be zero.